# How can magnetic dipole align if there is precession?

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, precession

In my lecture notes on paramagnetism and diamagnetism is stated that "according to van vleck critical considering an electron in motion around the nucleus diamagnetic and paramagnetic effect compensate (classical)"
The proof following takes the intrinsic momentum related to L as the momentum that in paramagnetism would "line up" due to the torque.
My question is, how can i have momentum alignment if there is larmor precession?

Comment: how does a ball rolling on a supposedly smooth surface stop without an *external* force? friction. An electron spin by itself will not stop precessing but a collection of electrons interacting with a crystal or magnetic moments interacting directly with each other and then thermalizing will align